# Excel COM Automation, 255 limit

Tags: excel, vba, com, spreadsheet

I use Excel.Application COM object to automate the generation of documentation that relies on Excel.

In essence, the input is a simple HTML string that only has span, bold and italic tags.

I erase the contents of the relevant cell, I parse this HTML string and I append characters to the relevant cell adjusting the font and font color, like so:

```
offset = Range.Characters().Count
Range.Characters(offset + 1).Insert("Hello");
Range.Characters(offset + 1).Font.Bold = True
```

It works fine for content less than 255 characters, but reaching that number, nothing is appended to the cell and the offset is always 255.

Any ideas? If I open excel and I write stuff manually into the cell I do not have this limitation.

Comment: I believe that's a known issue with using the Characters collection.

Comment: Can you provide a representative example of the type of HTML you want to show in a cell?

Comment: An example could be just <b>255 characters</b> for example, an HTML as simple as that. I was thinking that maybe the 255 character column width might be related to this, but I could not understand how, I was thinking that maybe activating the cell makes a difference somehow, as when one writes stuff manually the Excel cell is activated. I have yet to try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will summarize what worked for me:

1. First, extract from the HTML string the text and set the value of the cell to that text, this is the HTML without tags and unescaped, like so:

```
Range.Value = html_text
```

2. Use the Characters object to modify the format as necessary, Characters.Count will not truncate to 255, now it will return the real length of the string, like so:

```
Range.Characters(offset, format_length).Font.Bold = True
```

This way, I do not use the Insert method in characters, which seemed to be the one causing issues. Tried this with HTML strings up to 1000 characters with success. Also note that I am using COM (Excel.Application) from Python rather than VBA, in the latter this might not be trivial to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround which relies on Excel being able to open a file which just contains HTML formatted into a table:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    HTMLtoRange ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value, ActiveSheet.Range("B4")
End Sub

'Take some HTML, write it to a file as a table,
'   open the file in Excel, and copy A1 to `c`
Sub HTMLtoRange(HTML As String, c As Range)
    Dim fName As String
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        fName = .getSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\" & .getTempName() & ".xls"
        .opentextfile(fName, 2, True).write _         
                          "<html><table><tr><td>" & HTML & _
                          "</td></tr></table></html>"
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Workbooks.Open(fName)
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy c
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Input and output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks much simpler that any other workaround I've seen, will try it probably sometime today.

Comment: There are a couple of other approaches (but more complex) if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: I tried this but I was having problems when copying to a merged cell or when the HTML string contained line endings or break tags, I posted what worked for me, which is using mu current algorithm a bit different but it works quite well.